# Polarization of light - Malus's law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, polarization

I have recently learnt about polarization of light and Malus's Law. Also, I have learnt that a single polaroid allows half of the intensity of light incident on it to pass through (assuming that the incident light was unpolarized).

So if we have two polaroids that are placed with their pass axis at $\theta$ to each other and the intensity of light incident on the first polaroid is $I_o$, then what will the intensity of the emergent light (light emerging from the second polaroid) be?

According to me, the answer should be $\frac{I_o}{2}\cos^2\theta$
Is this correct? Or would it simply be $I_o\cos^2\theta$?

Comment: It appears that you are correct. Shall I add a perfunctory answer to the purpose?

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury No it's okay xD I just had this basic confusion. Thanks.

Comment: I should add one anyway. Not everyone goes through the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are correct.**

## Longer explanation:

When unpolarized light of intensity $I_0$ passes through a Polaroid filter (sometimes referred to as a "polarizer"), it becomes plane-polarized as it passes out of it and its intensity is halved in the process, becoming $\frac{I_0}{2}$.

When this plane-polarized light passes through the second Polaroid filter (sometimes referred to as a "analyzer"), Malus' Law becomes applicable. As the Polaroids' axes are tilted at $\theta$ to each other, the intensity of light after passing through the analyzer becomes $\frac{I_0}{2}\cos^2\theta$ , in accordance with Malus' Law.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way one Polaroid at a time.
Also first consider amplitudes and then square the amplitude to get the intensity.

First Polaroid with randomly polarised (in polarised) incident light.

Resolve the incident amplitudes into components parallel to the axis of the Polaroid which passes through the Polaroid and at right angles to the axis of the Polaroid which is absorbed by the Polaroid.

When you do this for all the incident waves you get an amplitude of $\frac{A}{\sqrt{2}}$ getting through the Polaroid.
So the incident intensity $I_o \;(\propto A^2)$ becomes $\frac{I_o}{2} \;(\propto \left (\frac{A}{\sqrt{2}}\right )^2)$

Caontinuing with amplitudes and again resolving into two components parallel and perpendicular to the axis of the next Polaroid gives $\frac{I_o}{2} \cos^2\theta\;(\propto \left (\frac{A}{\sqrt{2}}\cos \theta\right )^2)$

Answer (score -1):

When polarized light passes through a polarizer, only the component of amplitude of the electric field that is in the direction of the polarizing plane will pass through.

component = $A_0$ cosθ

The intensity of light (I) is proportional to $A^2$ so if the original intensity of the polarized light was $I_0$, the intensity passing through the polarizer will be given by the equation

I = $I_0$ $cos^2$θ

This is called Malus’ law.